# How can I provide a favicon.ico from the server?

Tags: typescript, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

Repo: https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/boilerplate/tree/SSR-TEMPLATE

This is a custom made SSR application and I'm NOT using Next.

The current setup also works for my devServer, I just can't get the favicon.ico to work when trying to run just the server from my "start" script.

This is my file structure:

```
├── assets
│   └── favicon.ico
├── client
│   ├── components
│   │   └── App.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
├── config
│   ├── tsconfig.client.json
│   ├── tsconfig.server.json
│   ├── webpack.client.config.ts
│   └── webpack.server.config.ts
├── dist
│   ├── client
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── server
│   │   ├── views
|   │   │   └── index.hbs
│   │   └── server.js
├── node_modules
├── server
│   ├── server.ts
│   └── views
│       └── index.hbs
├── types
│   └── custom.d.ts
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Within my server.tsx I am using the dist/client for any static assets:

```
app.use( express.static( path.resolve( __dirname, '../dist/client' ) ) )
```

I also believe my config is setup properly for my webpack.server.config:

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: './server/server.tsx',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, '../dist/server' ),
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx' ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin( {
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: path.resolve( __dirname, '../server/views' ),
                    to: path.resolve( __dirname, '../dist/server/views' ),
                },
                {
                    from: path.resolve( __dirname, '../assets/favicon.ico' ),
                    to: path.resolve( __dirname, '../dist/client/' ),
                },
            ],
        } ),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(tsx?|js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
}

export default config
```

this is the error I'm seeing:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

-Best practice would assume that I need to move my copyWebpackPlugin over to the client configuration, but I get a blob error when I move the configuration around, which is super weird..

Comment: What is the exact error? Please [edit] your question to include it as well as the version of your config that causes the error.

Comment: I updated the post to display the error near the bottom. -Thanks

Comment: How are you running the app? Is this from `npm start` or something similar?

Comment: p.s. I'm not very familiar with server side rendering. I'm just asking some clarifying questions to see if I can perhaps figure something out.

Comment: I am using yarn. After downloading the repo, you should just have to install dependencies and do a "yarn build" before running the "start" or "dev" script.

Comment: I used chat-GPT 4 to help me setup this template, it's been a really cool learning experience. I'm not familiar with SSR, but I know typescript, react, and everything else and I finally just got this thing working so I'm super happy about it. I just need to get the icon to work from the server and I'll have no errors.

Comment: In my experience, assets such as the favicon are served by the HTTP server, such as nginx or apache. IDK if SSR is different in that respect. You might double check that the favicon is actually on your server and that it permissions are correct for the HTTP server to find it.

Comment: oh dood, you're the best! I had messed up and had to change my path here:

```
app.use( express.static( path.resolve( __dirname, '../client' ) ) )
```
- I was assuming the path was from my server/server.tsx and not from the dist/server/server.js

Thank you sir!